# Restriction based on IP ranges

Tags: php, ip, range

I am building an admin panel. and I want to block certain IP ranges. I'm testing this on my localhost wamp server but ir doesn't seem to redirect me.

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0..*') 
      header("Location: http://google.com");
   else
      echo "Hai";
?>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to check for subnets too e.g. `127.0.0.0` thru `127.0.0.15`?

Comment: Its not a duplicate if you compare the two questions in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is sufficient to use string comparison

```
if (strncmp('127.0.0.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 8) === 0)
  header("Location: http://google.com");
else
  echo "Hai";
```

Update: Taken from the comments of inits answer

> Suppose i want to block any IP coming from this range: 192.168.0.1-255. What would be the best solution for it ? Thanks.

Then just make the same string comparison against this block

```
if (strncmp('192.168.0.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 10) === 0)
  header("Location: http://google.com");
else
  echo "Hai";
```

If you want to test the remote address against both blocks at once, you will probably put them together into one expression. This time we need a different approach

```
if (in_array(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '.')), array('127.0.0', '192.168.0'))) {
  header("Location: http://google.com");
else
  echo "Hai";
```

The `substr()`-part takes the IP until the last `.`. We can just try to find this string in a set (-> array) of IP-prefixes.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ip0 = ip2long("127.0.0.1");
$ip1 = ip2long("127.0.0.254");
$ip  = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($ip0 <= $ip && $ip <= $ip1) {
    echo long2ip($ip) . " is inside  range " . long2ip($ip0) . "-" . long2ip($ip1);
}
else {
    echo long2ip($ip) . " is outside range " . long2ip($ip0) . "-" . long2ip($ip1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better approach, using regualr expression:

```
// returns true for IPs 127.0.0.0-255
if (preg_match("'^127[.]0[.]0[.][0-9]+'",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
else
{
    echo "Hai";
}
```

**EDIT:** Fine, take it to another level, maybe not the most effective, but easier to configure:

```
$mask = "192.168.1.1-255";

$ip = explode(".",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$in = 0;
foreach (explode(".",$mask) as $k => $v)
{
    if (preg_match("'^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$'",$v,$n))
    {
        if ($ip[$k] >= $n[1] && $ip[$k] <= $n[2]) $in++;
    }
    elseif (preg_match("'^[0-9]+$'",$v,$n))
    {
        if ($ip[$k] == $n[0]) $in++;
    }
}
if ($in == 4)
{
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
else
{
    echo "Hai";
}
```

Comment: The real regex should be: `^127\.0\.0\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`. (Just to mention: The downvote wasnt me ;))

Comment: No need for a slow regex here. Simple substr, strcmp or strncmp should suffice. edit: also I didn't downvote

Comment: Suppose i want to block any IP coming from this range: 192.168.0.1-255. What would be the best solution for it ? Thanks.

Comment: Regex is an undigestable freak of nature, deserving to be punished by all means of black magic and downvoting :D (No problem btw, and thx for the proper regex @KingCrunch).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem of just allowing some fixed IPs and some IP ranges:

```
$ClientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$First3PartsOfIP = substr($ClientIP, 0, strrpos($ClientIP, '.'));
$AllowedIPs = ['127.0.0.1'];
$AllowedFirst3Parts = ['172.20.8', '172.21.13'];
if (!in_array($ClientIP, $AllowedIPs) && !in_array($First3PartsOfIP, $AllowedFirst3Parts)) {
    //echo "Your IP: $ClientIP<br />";
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```